# unpredictable C++ sleep/wait behavior

Tags: c++, sleep

I must be doing something stupid because I am getting the weirdest behavior from this simple sleep code. Originally I was using std::this_thread::sleep_for and got the same results but assumed it must have been some thread strangeness. However, I am getting the same seemingly out-of-order waiting with the code below. Same results with clang++ or g++. I am on Debian and compiling at the command line.

Expected behavior:
Shutting down in 3... [wait one second] 2... [wait one second] 1... [wait one second; program exit]

Actual behavior:
[3 second long wait] Shutting down in 3... 2... 1... [program exit]

```
#include<chrono>
#include<iostream>

void Sleep(int i) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    while (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now-start).count() < i)
        now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}

void ShutdownCountdown(int i) {
    if (i <= 0) return;

    std::cout << "Shutting down in ";
    for (; i != 0; --i) {
        std::cout << i << "... ";
        Sleep(1);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ShutdownCountdown(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add `<< std::flush;` after printing stuff in the loop body.

Comment: Unrelated: careful with using `high_resolution_clock` like this. It really sucks when it's actually an alias for `system_clock` and daylight savings time hits. Use `steady_clock` instead.

Comment: Thanks so much, HolyBlackCat! I don't know how I have never run into the std::flush problem before.... And good note, user4581301, I am using this_thread::sleep_for in the actual code--I just changed the code to what I posted because I wasn't sure if I was doing something dumb with threading that was causing the problem.

Comment: std::endl also does a flush, so depending on how you had the code before you may have had this behaviour and not noticed it

Comment: @Hitobat: Actually the stream looks for the `'\n'` character and does a flush, doesn't matter whether it comes from `std::endl` or any other source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally `iostream`s do not flush until a newline is encountered. Since you don't output an EOL character, you need to explicitly flush to get the output printed:

```
        std::cout << i << "... " << std::flush;
```

---

Unrelated, but note also the CPU getting a bit *hot* when you run your program. To save energy, consider changing the busy loop back to a real [sleep](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for):

```
    for (; i != 0; --i) {
        std::cout << i << "... " << std::flush;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
```

The nifty "`1s`" syntax is possible with `using namespace std::chrono_literals;` at the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<chrono>
#include<iostream>

void Sleep(int i) {
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
while (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now-start).count() < i)
    now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}

void ShutdownCountdown(int i) {
if (i <= 0) return;

std::cout << "Shutting down in "<<std::flush;
for (; i != 0; --i) {
    std::cout << i << "... "<<std::flush;
    Sleep(1);
}
std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
ShutdownCountdown(3);

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation rather than a code-only answer

Comment: Code-only answers have an annoying tendency to produce [Cargo Cult Programmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), and Crom knows we have too many of them already.